# Why doesn't my child class inherit my parent's string?

Tags: c++, class, object

I'm new to C++ and programming, so bear with me: I'm trying to store a string in my parent class for later use in a child class. But when I try to use my string in my child class, it doesn't output anything.

```
class parent
{
protected:
    std::string str;

public:
   void input()
   {
        std::cin >> str;
   }
};

class child : parent
{
public:
   void output()
   {
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
   }
};

int main()
{
   parent parent;
   child child;

   parent.input();
   child.output();
   return 0;
}
```

This also happens if I try to use an integer from my parent class. But for some reason, the code works, if I define my string or integer in the child class.

```
class child : parent
{
public:
    void output()
    {
        std::cin >> str >> std::endl;
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Thank you for your time reading my amateur question!

Comment: `parent parent; child child;` You create 2 unrelated instances. Because of which, your code sample boils down to `int a = 0; int b = 0; std::cin >> a; std::cout << b;`.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius is correct. And maybe you got it confused with `static` variables. But still, it's a long shot even to be confused. :|

Comment: Thank you for your input @AlgirdasPreidžius! But, how do I make the instances related? Sorry for the dumb questions - I'm really new to programming.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Again, please put your answers in the _answer section_, designed for that task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two individual class instances, not one. A `parent`, and a `child` (which inherits from `parent`). The two instances are unrelated and unconnected; modifying one does not influence the other, despite the inheritance heirarchy that's in place.

I think you meant this:

```
int main()
{
   child obj;

   obj.input();
   obj.output();
}
```

Now, though `input()` comes from the inherited `parent` part of the object, you're calling both functions on the same object with the same, shared state, and ought to see the expected result accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

First a note on inheritance. This

```
class child : parent
```

will use the default, `private` inheritance. It's the same as writing

```
class child : private parent
```

and it means that the parents `public` and `protected` members will be `private` in the child, hence the `input()` method will be unavailable from outside the child. The code *should* therefor not compile, if you later try to call the `input()` method on a child instance (i.e. from the outside). When starting with C++ you almost always want to make the inheritance public. So change it to:

```
class child : public parent
```

or

```
struct child : /* public */ parent   // struct has 'public' inheritance by default
```

You later create one `parent` and one `child` instance. I renamed the instances `p` and `c` for clarity. You should generally avoid using the same name for instances as for classes.

```
   parent p;
   child c;

   p.input();
   c.output();
```

`p` now contains (is composed of) one `std::string` instance named `str`. `c` also has one `std::string` instance named `str`, but they are different instances/objects (unless you make them `static`, but for now, don't). Each instance carries its own data. Even two instances of the same class do, so this would not repeat anything back either:

```
   child c1, c2;

   c1.input();
   c2.output();
```

However, this will work, since the same instance is used for both input and output:

```
   child c;

   c.input();
   c.output();
```